# Javascript loop that executes a post but it only executes the last value from the loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, kendo-ui, closures

I'm trying to execute multiple ids and add it in an object to be executed. so this is from an event button function:

```
{
for(var i =0; i< selectrows.length; i++){
   Action["trackid"] = selectrows[i].innerText.replace(/(^\d+)(.+$)/i, '$1');

   researchService.postExecuteAction(Action)
     .then(function(result){
     },function error(result){
     });
}
}
```

So for example the trackids are 111, 112, 113.
It will only execute trackid 113 for three times.
I would like to execute 111, 112 as well. I've tried many different ways of closure to handle these but it didn't work. I might be doing something wrong. Please help. Thank you.

Comment: `postExecuteAction` is called with 3 different `trackid`. What do you mean "*It will only execute trackid 113 for three times*"? Are you accessing `Action["trackid"]` inside the `.then()` callback?

Comment: you mentioned all but didn't mentioned selectrows[], what is stored inside it??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Probably because you reassign the Action["trackid"] on the same object.

Do something like:

```
{
for(var i =0; i< selectrows.length; i++){
   const action = { ...Action }
   action["trackid"] = selectrows[i].innerText.replace(/(^\d+)(.+$)/i, '$1');

   researchService.postExecuteAction(action)
     .then(function(result){
     },function error(result){
     });
}
}
```

Comment: @noobSoloDeveloper Did I miss something or why are you downvoting a correct answer?

Comment: Make sure to change all "Action" to "action"

Comment: Votes are anonymous, so I can't tell you who voted. But I _can_ tell you that it wasn't noobSoloDeveloper, because you need at least 125 reputation [to be able to downvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down).

Comment: Ah ok, weird people :)

Comment: @ArwedMett Thank you this is correct. Upon debugging, It now passes the correct values of action. However, my loop still executes only the last value multiple times.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand your question.